# Getting error while running the Mesos container in mesos cluster using marathon

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

```
"container": {
    "type": "MESOS",
    "docker": {
      "image": "redis",
      "forcePullImage": false
    }
  }
```

1. The above example has the container type as Mesos..but again specifying "docker" image... for using universal container or mesos container, do we need to install docker?
2. because, when i try to run a sample in mesos with type "mesos" container, i am getting error like this:

> unsupported container image:DOCKER.

I have not installed docker.

3. I am using Mesos1.1 version

Comment: What does the headline have to do with what you wrote in your question body? That's hard to understand... And, your Marathon app definition is incomplete

Comment: Thanks, do i need docker, to run a json which has container type : Mesos in mesos cluster...

Answer (score 0):

See https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html#mesos-containerizer-and-universal-container-runtime for a valid example on how to run a Docker image with the Mesos UCR.

```
{
    "id": "mesos-docker",
    "container": {
        "docker": {
            "image": "mesosphere/inky"
        },
        "type": "MESOS"
    },
    "args": ["hello"],
    "cpus": 0.2,
    "mem": 16.0,
    "instances": 1
}
```

You'll need Marathon >= 1.3.0 and Mesos >= 1.0 for that.

Comment: when i run the above example..I am getting the following error: unsupported container image: docker..so that i am asking, do we need docker, to run mesos type container also..

Comment: Have a look at http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/ (section "Docker Runtime Isolator")

Comment: @User12345 from the results you are getting, I would guess you do not have the "docker/runtime" isolator enabled.